# How to make search engines index objects in a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, seo, leaflet, google-search, mapbox

I have a webpage, which is basically all map, with **markers loaded from a CSV file**. There is a lot of info in the marker popup boxes. Logically, the HTML doesn't contain any text, it's all just JavaScript which loads the CSV, so **search engines don't index anything**.

Any ideas how to solve this? Don't store data in CSV? How then?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have search engines list your page with only a map in their results.

Search engines want textual content ...

What you can do however is to create pages containing the information meaningful for the user and link to your map from there

Comment: Well the content is there, it's just that it appears only after the user clicks on the marker. 

Maybe if I don't load it from a CSV file, but keep it in the HTML file as GeoJSON?

Comment: My guess is that only the content in html tags will be indexed. You could tag your question with google-search to get more answers on that

Answer (score 0):

if anyone reads this, you'll need to put content in a div under the map, to make the page more indexed that with its title and basic info attached.